# Query to merge data according to address type

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, merge

I have a table A as below:

```
ID Name Age 
1  A     18 
2  B     19
```

This table has a one-to-many mapping with the address table.

```
ID ParentID AddressType ALine1 ALine2 State City Country
10        1 Mail        AAA    AAA    AAB   CCC  CDCD
11        1 Home        BBB    BBA    BAB   CAC  CFCF
12        2 Mail        CAV    VAC    CSC   DFS  DDDC
```

I need to get the desired output:

```
Name Age Address1Type ALine1 ALine2 State1 City1 Country1 Address2Type A2Line1 A2Line2  State2 City2 Country2 
---- --- ------------ ------ ------ ------ ----- -------- ------------ ------- -------- ------ ----- --------
A     18 Mail         AAA    AAA    AAB    CCC   CDCD     Home         BBB     BBA      BAB    CAC   CFCF
B     19 Mail         CAV    VAC    CSC    DFS   DDDC     null         null    null     null   null  null
```

I am able to combine them but getting multiple records for same name. How can I get the output I need?

Comment: What is the SQL statement you have tried?

Comment: 'merge' is a DML operation to insert/update data in a table; do you really mean that, or are you just querying and want a result set that combines the data from both tables?

Comment: I am just querying tables  and want a result set that combines data from both the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT          parent.Name,
                parent.Age,
                mailInfo.*,
                homeInfo.*
FROM            parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses AS mailInfo
             ON parent.ID = mailInfo.ParentID
            AND mailInfo.AddressType = 'Mail'
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses AS homeInfo
             ON parent.ID = homeInfo.ParentID
            AND mailInfo.AddressType = 'Home';
```

Comment: Of course, this works only if you're looking for only the home- and mail-addresses

Comment: Thank you so much Robert it did help !!